# Save subclass of SKShapeNode using NSCoding

Tags: sprite-kit, nskeyedarchiver, nscoding

I have a subclass of `SKShapenode` with 2 extra attributes

```
@property(assign)float size;
@property(assign)float weight;
```

But when I save a `NSMutableArray`, with core data, containing some subclasses of my node, the information about size + weight is lost.

```
newLevel.tractorObjects = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:arrayTractorObjects];
```

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you appear to be using `NSCoding` to encode the nodes, you need to implement `NSCoding` in your subclass. Right now `SKShapeNode` is doing all of the encoding, but it doesn't know about your subclass attributes. To get your attributes encoded, you need to implement `encodeWithCoder` and `initWithCoder`. Both of these should call `super`'s implementation so that `SKShapeNode` can encode itself, and then add/extract your own attributes.

Comment: When I do this:
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)decoder {
    
    if (self = [super init])
    {
        self.weight = [decoder decodeFloatForKey:@"weight"];
        self.size = [decoder decodeFloatForKey:@"size"];
    }
    
    return self;
}

- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)encoder
{
    
    [super encodeWithCoder:encoder];
    
    [encoder encodeFloat:self.weight forKey:@"weight"];
    [encoder encodeFloat:self.size forKey:@"size"];
}
Informations about position+rect+ other informations about the Node are lost.

Comment: I wasn't kidding when I said that **both** of those need to call super's implementation.

Comment: could you please provide an extra line or two showing how a subclass should call the supers ? Is it just `super.encode(with: aCoder);
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)` then followed by all of the subclass properties?

Comment: That should be all that's needed.